# How to import materials to a downloaded model?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, import

Beginner question here. I just downloaded this pokemon model from models resource https://www.models-resource.com/3ds/pokemonxy/model/9320/ and used Blender Source Tools to import it into Blender. When I imported the model however and switched from solid to textured mode, the model is just pure white. No texture at all.

I know about having to unwrap and deal with the whole uv map shenanigans, which is something I really don't want to do, especially considering the 70+ models that I want to edit to add some extras to them so they could be even better for animations in Source Filmmakeer.

I've searched all over Youtube and every video I've seen where the person imported an smd file didn't have the textures applied, but when I watched someone's video where they imported an obj file, the textures were automatically applied. (Though that was in Blender 2.66a, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it) I could use a little help with figuring out how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These guys actually have UVmaps. Just import the DAE file, go to Material view instead of Texture view and check in Shadeless for every material.
[image]